# react native flat list horizontal RTL auto scroll issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

i have problem with my flat list horizontal when open screen start from first item then it scroll to another item when
i use scroll view with map it fix the problem but i want to use flat list
this is what should happend it should open to first item

[image]

this is what realy happend after open screen it is auto scroll to another item

[image]

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 10 }}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={this.state.BrandList}
  renderItem={this._renderListItem}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  horizontal
/>;
```

Comment: It is still an open issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19150

Comment: Hi, you can check my solution. Here is how i created my RTL friendly Flatlist component https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19150#issuecomment-1012249555

Answer (score 2):

in RTL layout you can use this way for solving this problem:

```
<FlatList
    nestedScrollEnabled
    // for better show data in list you should reverse data
    data={Calendar.reverse()}
    keyExtractor={item => item.visit_day_identity}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    horizontal
    pagingEnabled
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    snapToEnd
    ref={element}
    // this attr is scrolled to start
    inverted={true}
/>
```